# Xcode 6.1 IOS really long form

Tags: ios

I am quite new to xcode.

I am trying to create a contact details form for an iPhone using the storyboard. The problem is that form is longer than the display and I can't work out how to design it using the storyboard.

Any ideas?

Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such forms are often made in storyboards using a `UITableView` and setting the "content" of the table to be "Static Cells." You can set any number of cells and the contents of the cell you want. The table itself is scrollable inside the storyboard/Interface Builder editor and looks much the way it would when presented to a user.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is the way I did this

Answer (score 9):

In IB, you can set the controller's size in Simulated Metrics to Freeform, then select the view and make it as tall as you want. Then, add a scroll view to take up the whole view, and add your UIElements, and lay them out how you want. When you run the app, the view controller will still only be as big as the screen (obviously), but the scroll view will be as big as you made the view in IB (you may need to increase its `contentSize` even more to be able to scroll to the bottom).

Comment: Whoever marked this down should explain why this isn't a useful answer.

Comment: Not me. But I have a question: with your solution how do you add an UIButton at the position (example) (10, 600) of the scroll view?

Answer (score 2):

First, select the tableView on the left

[image: select tableView]

Then, you can move it simply scrolling (on mac, two fingers on the trackpad, or using the mouse wheel)

[image: scroll]

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at UIScrollView, it is designed to support content larger than screen size (like you see in web browser or settings)

Basic usage is:

```
//Set a size which will be able to cover all form elements
[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake()]; 

//Your scrollView now extends from CGPoint 0,0 to contentSize.width,contentSize.height.
//Your subviews should be positioned according to scrollview's bounds not the viewcontroller.view or any other container view.

//Add all the form elements
[yourScrollView addSubview:...]; 

[yourScrollView setDelegate:self]; //If you need actions after user scrolled etc.
```

Have a look at the developer manual for more info. Most method names are quite self explanatory. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: He is asking about scrolling the view when working inside IB, not at runtime

Comment: it doesn't look like that to me, he says he is new to xcode doesn't even mention he uses a scrollview, tableview or smt similar. Even if so, he will not be able to design uiscrollview in storyboard so my answer still holds.

Comment: "how to design it using the storyboard" seems pretty clear. Moreover, he can design UIScrollView in storyboard, even if it's not so "confortable". It's sufficient to add a NIB to the project, drag a new UIScrollView inside an empty area of this nib, configure it at the desired size, when finished copy/paste inside the storyboard and delete the nib

Comment: he is new to xcode but pro in objc and ios dev you made a great inference, look at some other answers they also posted which control to use. if he doesn't like my answer he comments and/or doesn't accept it, i don't get why it is such a big problem for you. Also he asks for a solution with storyboards and you can only give an alternative with nib files, look at rdelmar's answer it is much better than yours to design scrollviews in storyboard. Feel free to comment further, i'm not going to answer back.